# problem in creating .xls file in Hebrew/arabic language with format in php

Tags: phpexcel

i am facing a problem with creating a .xls file in Hebrew/arabic language in php.
When i create a file then all of the field created that in english.But field in Hebrew language field has created in unreadable format.

if anyone can help me?
i m waiting...........

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show some of the code you are using to generate the file, and an example of what happens to the characters.

Comment: Thanks for being so quick. Actually its a simple code for writing an excel file. I want to explain my question a bit more that will help you I believe:
I have a database table with fields values in hebrew language (a unicode based language). Now I wrote a php script which downloads all the fields of that table along with their values. But the hebrew characters are displaying something like garbage. So, this is the problem for me. I think the issue is related to headers used in script and utf8 ecoding. Please let me know if you still need the code. I will provide a link to you. Thanks again.

Comment: yup, it probably is related to the encoding. However, it would be much preferable if you could paste the relevant parts of your code in here. That way, the problem's solution has a use for future generations as well

Comment: PHPExcel uses UTF-8 encoding internally, and saves the Excel workbook using UTF-8 encoding; but it doesn't automatically convert encodings in any way. You need to ensure that all your string data is converted to UTF-8 before setting the cell values.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for providing such a good library. Everything is working finally fine at my end. I can get the Hebrew languages into my excel sheet from the database. Really good one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use phpexcel library for this purpose. Its works great. You can download the library from here:
http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/